3D mesh with CGAL: surface smoothing problem when several domains are defined
I am using CGAL to generate a 3d mesh from segmented images, which can include different domains. When only one domain is defined in my images, I obtain a reasonably smooth mesh (see image below).

However, when adding more domains, the surface of my mesh is not smooth anymore (see image below). I tried to use odt_optimize_mesh_3, lloyd_optimize_mesh_3 and perturb_mesh_3 to improve the mesh quality but it remains fairly bad when more than one domain appear in my segmented images.

I am not sure to understand why the mesh quality deteriorates so much. Additionally, when I look at the examples given in the documentation of CGAL, it seems that CGAL should handle very well my problem, so I assume I am doing something wrong. Here is a minimal working example of my code:
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkXMLImageDataReader.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>

#include <CGAL/Image_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Labeled_mesh_domain_3.h>
#include <CGAL/read_vtk_image_data.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>

#include <CGAL/IO/output_to_vtu.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_mesh_3.h>


#ifdef CGAL_CONCURRENT_MESH_3
  typedef CGAL::Parallel_tag Concurrency_tag;
#else
  typedef CGAL::Sequential_tag Concurrency_tag;
#endif

typedef CGAL::Image_3 Image;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Labeled_mesh_domain_3<K> Mesh_domain;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<Mesh_domain,CGAL::Default,Concurrency_tag>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Mesh_criteria;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C3t3;

namespace params = CGAL::parameters;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Read image from file
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLImageDataReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLImageDataReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName(argv[1]);
    reader->Update();

    vtkImageData* imageData = reader->GetOutput();

    int dims[3];
    imageData->GetDimensions(dims);
    double spacing[3];
    imageData->GetSpacing(spacing);
    double origin[3];
    imageData->GetOrigin(origin);
    
    CGAL::Image_3 image = CGAL::read_vtk_image_data(imageData) ;

    // Define the mesh domain
    Mesh_domain domain = Mesh_domain::create_labeled_image_mesh_domain(image);

    // Define meshing criteria
    Mesh_criteria criteria(params::facet_angle = 30,
                           params::facet_size = 10,
                           params::facet_distance =5,
                           params::cell_radius_edge_ratio = 10,
                           params::cell_size = 10);

    // Generate mesh
    C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria);

    // Write mesh to vtu
    std::ofstream vtu_file("output_mesh.vtu");
    vtu_file.precision(17);
    CGAL::output_to_vtu(vtu_file, c3t3, CGAL::IO::BINARY);

    return 0;
}


Does anyone have a suggestion about what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

To have the feature lines nicely represented in the output mesh, the user needs to specify explicitly that they must be detected, and protected.
In your case, the feature lines are the polylines lying at the intersection of 2 subdomains and the "outside".
More explanations can be found in the CGAL documentation, and an example here.
